# laravel internal 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, internal

I uploaded my website to a server that is using windows server 2008 r2 and Im getting a problem  ( I think its caused because of the .htaccess files ) I get internal 500 error message, im using xampp

My website its not directly on htdocs folder, its on htdocs/server/ maybe that can be an issue?

Also heres my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you created the virtual host in the httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Windows Server will obey your **.htaccess**.
Try define the same logic in your **webconfig** file.
First of all, you need to direct it to have as your website root, the public folder.
And then **inside** this folder, try this **web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Best wishes